# R reticulate: Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords): RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, r, reticulate, recursionerror

I have the following python function to extract unique object names in an AWS S3 bucket, and it passed the test runs in python:

```
###############################
# aws_get_session_name_fuc.py #
###############################
def get_session_names(s3, BUCKET, session_path):
    session_names = []
    unique_session_names = []
    n = 2
    session_archives = s3.Bucket(BUCKET).objects.filter(Prefix = session_path)

    # Extract object names from path
    for i in session_archives:
        temp_str = i.key.split('/')
        session_names.append(temp_str[n])

    # obtain unique object names
    for i in session_names:
        if i not in unique_session_names:
            unique_session_names.append(i)
    return unique_session_names

'''
# Test
test_extract = get_session_names(s3, BUCKET, session_path)
test_extract
Out[19]: 
['',
 'testSession01',
 'testSession02',
 'testSession03']
'''
```

When I run the above script using `reticulate::source_python("aws_get_session_name_fuc.py")` in R, I would get the following error:

```
> existing_session = get_session_names(s3, BUCKET, session_path)
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I tried to increase the recursion limit in the python script using `sys.setrecursionlimit()`, it would either trigger the same error when the value is not "large enough", or crash the R session if the value was "too large":

- Recursion limit value not "large enough":
  [image]
- Recursion limit value "too large":
  [image]

So, I'm trying to understand:

1. Why does the function pass in Python, but fail when referenced in
   R?
2. Is there a better way to resolve this?

**EDIT-1:**

I managed to resolve this problem by converting the defined function into script, and then using `reticulate::py_run_file("python/aws_get_session_name_script.py")` directly to obtain the extraction, write results to file, and then load back into R.

Comment: May be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it

Comment: @niranjan-poudel Increasing the recursion limit doesn't work for my scenario, unfortunately.